# Log shipping backup

Tags: sql-server-2012, log-shipping

I m confused with backup for log shipping,by taking full backup(not copy- only) in primary ,does it affect the log backup LSN chain and cause log shipping not to work? If it does not affect LSN chain, can i take full backup and differential backup in primary and then for log backup can i use log backup which is done by log shipping in shared folder for restoration incase primary and secondary server down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By taking full backup(not copy- only) in primary ,does it affect the log backup LSN chain and cause log shipping not to work?

No..Never. Full backup has NO affect on transaction log backup chain it is not going to break the logshipping. I strongly suggest you to read [Backup Myths](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-3030-backup-myths/) section by Paul Randal.

> can i take full backup and differential backup in primary and then for log backup can i use log backup which is done by log shipping in shared folder for restoration in case primary and secondary server down.

Yes you can, neither full nor diff backup would break log shipping, although your request seems strange to me. If their is LS database and you want to restore full, diff and log backup make sure you do not let log backups be deleted from shared drive after the threshold is crossed in LS.

Answer (score 0):

Full backup has nothing to do with LSN,

important thing is that suppose you are going for restore on primary, than you will select any of the full backup

- if you pick the one taken at routine sql agent full backup job
  You need to follow all TLogs taken after that (including those taken in log shipping)
- if you pick the one taken at for log shipping
  then you will restore only those tlogs taken after log shipping process.